# Twitter bearer token (use in Java)

Tags: java, twitter, bearer-token

I am facing an issue in getting the twitter bearer token for my application.

Although, I received the successful response from Twitter as mentioned below:
"POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials returned a response status of 200 OK".

But when I try to retrieve the bearer token from the response by using the below statement, I get a long queue of junk characters:

```
String str = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

Further to that i tried two more approaches:

1) The getHeaders method returned:

```
content-disposition=[attachment; filename=json.json]
```

So, it looks like that server is sending back the token in an attachment file so I changed the above to:

```
File r_file = response.getEntity(File.class);
```

But this temp file also consists of junk characters only

2) I tried to decode these characters using Base64, but even that threw back an error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing your application in Java, or something else ?
here's a [link](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/single-user) from twitter documentation on examples for a number of languages

Comment: I am writing it in JAVA. I believe language wont be a limitation to that, right?

Comment: Not at all, are you using a twitter API wrapper of any sort, [twitter4j] is fairly easy with good examples (twitter4j.org/en/)

Comment: No, i am just using the JAX-RS jersey libraries to send & read requests & responses but nothing else.

Comment: Twitter4j manages your GET, POST requests, You just need to configure it correctly and provide your Token, while configuring the file that will receive the response with your OAuth token and credentials, Then you can go back to using the API using these tokens the way you prefer, although I'm interested in your approach, but I'm yet to find reasons why to change my application into web services.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
I was trying to get the Bearer token from Android client using the Volley library for the network connection. The response status was `200 OK`, however the response body was a string, full of funny junk characters.
I was setting manually 3 headers :

```
"Authorization": "Basic .....", 
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
```

After removing the `"Accept-Encoding"` header everything went OK. The response was the expected well formatted JSON:

```
{"token_type": "bearer", "access_token": "......."}
```